# how to create setup wizard with C win32 CodeBlocks?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-installer, installation, codeblocks

I heard Code Blocks doesn't have an integrated tool to handle setup creations, but I was wondering if there are any Windows API functions that I could use.
 I found there are some on MSDN, namely MSI functions. Dunno what that's all about.. Would experiment, but I lack msi libraries. 
 Searching hasn't helped me find them.. 
Help please !!

EDIT: At least is there a function similar to `FolderBrowserDialog`, that would prompt a dialog box for the user to select a path to install/extract some files ? `FolderBrowserDialog` is a method within a class in C++.. I'm looking for such a function in C.

Comment: Just use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Found [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx) for browsing a folder. It would be cool if the correct answer to the main question would add this information, for it was hard to come by.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend creating installation packages using the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). It's very powerful and creates very good MSI packages. It's also Open Source so if you are curious how it does its work, you can see that as well.

Comment: I'm aware I can use other software for that.. just wanna know if there is anything I can do in C.

Comment: You can rewrite the WiX toolset in C if you like. The code is Open Source so you can read it all. That's why I recommended the WiX toolset over other alternatives. :)